# why is regular expression matching this text?

Tags: regex, grep

Why is grep -noE '<math>.*</math>' matching

> <math>w</math>, from a set of <math>w</math>
>   special binary fractions, <math>V_i, i = 1, 2, \dots,
>   w</math> called direction numbers. The bits of the [[Gray code]]
>   of <math>i</math>, <math>G(i)</math>, are used
>   to select direction numbers. To get the Sobol sequence value
>   <math>s_i</math> take the [[exclusive or]] of the binary
>   value of the Gray code of<math>i</math> with the
>   appropriate direction number. The number of dimensions required
>   affects the choice of <math>V_i</math>
>   37196767:<math> \int_0^1 f(u)\,du \approx
>   \frac{1}{N}\,\sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i). </math>

I would just like to have each element on its own, and not be greedy.

Comment: Because there's more than one </math> text that matches the opening math tag.

Comment: It would also help if you post how you like the output to be.

Comment: @Jhecht: wouldn't it be easier if you just helped me fix this, rather than downvote? You just lost two points, when you could have won 10?

Comment: Didn't down vote you, when I wrote my comment yours hadn't shown up yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify non-greedy version: `.*?`, but `grep` regular expression does not support it.

If you use [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), you can use `-P` option (or `--perl-regexp`):

```
grep -noP '<math>.*?</math>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
grep -noE '<math>[^<]*</math>'
```

Instead of matching any sequence between `<math>` and `</math>`, this will not allow `<` in the sequence, so it won't allow `</math>` inside.

It also won't allow any other tags, but it looks like that's not a problem for your text.

If you were using a tool that supports PCRE, you could use a non-greedy regexp:

```
<math>.*?</math>
```

Standard `grep` doesn't use PCRE, but if you use GNU grep you can use the `-P` option for this.

Answer (score 1):

Since `.*` is greedy, it will match from first found  `<math>` to last found `</math>`

Comment: I would like for it not to be greedy, is there a way to do that with grep?